# Can't set sequenceGenerator when generator strategy set to IDENTITY

Tags: postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am trying to set the allocation size and initial value of a sequence using the IDENTITY strategy for PostgreSQL.  This doesn't produce the SQL I expected, changing the strategy to SEQUENCE works however.  Is this intended?

```
id:
    id:
        type: integer
        id: true
        generator:
            strategy: IDENTITY
        sequenceGenerator:
            sequenceName: table_id_seq
            allocationSize: 10
            initialValue: 100000
```

Comment: I believe allocationSize is irrelevant when using IDENTITY as there are no nextval() requests when INSERTing rows.  However I'd still like to set the initial sequence value when creating the table.

Answer (score 4):

Doctrine initializes the ID generator strategy in `Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory`. There is a big `switch` statement in the factory, switching the `<STRATEGY_NAME>` you provide in your YAML configuration:

```
generator:
    strategy: <STRATEGY_NAME>
```

The selected strategy then fetches further optional parameters from your configuration.

All available strategies are listed in the [Doctrine Manual](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html?highlight=generator#identifier-generation-strategies). The options for the `Sequence Generator` strategy are detailed in the [following subsection](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html?highlight=generator#sequence-generator).

Judging from your configuration, you are currently setting the parameters for the `Sequence Generator` strategy, while telling Doctrine to use the `Identifier` strategy. Maybe this is the unexpected behavior you are experiencing?

You may [read the source code](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/v2.4.7/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php#L446-L503)  of the respective factory lines to clarify your expectations.

Answer (score 3):

So, use only with @GeneratedValue(strategy=”SEQUENCE”).

> For use with @GeneratedValue(strategy=”SEQUENCE”) this annotation allows to specify details about the sequence, such as the increment size and initial values of the sequence.

other [doctrine documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-sequencegenerator)

config example:

```
Message:
  type: entity
  id:
    id:
      type: integer
      generator:
        strategy: SEQUENCE
      sequenceGenerator:
        sequenceName: message_seq
        allocationSize: 100
        initialValue: 1
```

[look documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#identifier-generation-strategies)